# How to figure out constraint/variable for INFEASIBLITY?

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools, cp-sat

I am finding it difficult to figure out, because of which constraint the model returns INFEASEBLE. The infeasibility is only returned when I change some value of aparameter. For smaller values the model returns OPTIMAL solution. Here is the LOG when I get INFEASIBLE for higher value of the parameter:

```
Starting CP-SAT solver v9.5.2237
Parameters: max_time_in_seconds: 100 log_search_progress: true num_search_workers: 8

Initial optimization model '': (model_fingerprint: 0x17f955ab0e9f41c4)
#Variables: 350 (#bools:8 in objective)
  - 216 Booleans in [0,1]
  - 2 in [-28800,28800]
  - 16 in [-14400,14400]
  - 1 in [-40,60]
  - 2 in [0,60]
  - 9 in [0,120]
  - 16 in [0,28800]
  - 8 in [0,10000000]
  - 18 in [0,99999999999999]
  - 16 in [0,99999999999999999]
  - 1 in [1,28800]
  - 1 in [1,10000000]
  - 27 in [1,99999999999999999]
  - 8 in [1,999999999999999999]
  - 8 in [10,33][47,70]
  - 1 in [10,70]
#kBoolAnd: 32 (#enforced: 32) (#literals: 64)
#kBoolOr: 44 (#literals: 144)
#kIntDiv: 33
#kIntProd: 51
#kLinMax: 2 (#expressions: 16)
#kLinear1: 136 (#enforced: 128)
#kLinear2: 135 (#enforced: 119)
#kLinear3: 9
#kLinearN: 20 (#terms: 180)

Starting presolve at 0.00s
[ExtractEncodingFromLinear] #potential_supersets=0 #potential_subsets=0 #at_most_one_encodings=0 #exactly_one_encodings=0 #unique_terms=0 #multiple_terms=0 #literals=0 time=3.96e-06s
[Probing] implications and bool_or (work_done=108).
INFEASIBLE: 'during probing'

Presolve summary:
  - 52 affine relations were detected.
  - rule 'TODO dual: make encoding equiv?' was applied 96 times.
  - rule 'TODO dual: only one blocking constraint?' was applied 292 times.
  - rule 'TODO dual: only one blocking enforced constraint?' was applied 238 times.
  - rule 'TODO dual: only one unspecified blocking constraint?' was applied 166 times.
  - rule 'affine: new relation' was applied 52 times.
  - rule 'bool_and: x => x' was applied 16 times.
  - rule 'bool_or: implications' was applied 16 times.
  - rule 'dual: enforced equivalence' was applied 16 times.
  - rule 'dual: equivalent Boolean in near-duplicate constraints' was applied 16 times.
  - rule 'int_div: linearize positive division with a constant divisor' was applied 16 times.
  - rule 'int_prod: linearize product by constant.' was applied 4 times.
  - rule 'int_prod: reduced target domain.' was applied 38 times.
  - rule 'int_prod: removed constant expressions.' was applied 4 times.
  - rule 'int_square: reduced expr domain.' was applied 8 times.
  - rule 'int_square: reduced target domain.' was applied 16 times.
  - rule 'lin_max: target domain reduced' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'linear1: without enforcement' was applied 8 times.
  - rule 'linear: divide by GCD' was applied 128 times.
  - rule 'linear: reduced variable domains' was applied 38 times.
  - rule 'linear: remapped using affine relations' was applied 276 times.
  - rule 'linear: simplified rhs' was applied 249 times.
  - rule 'linear: simplify using approximate gcd' was applied 18 times.
  - rule 'linear: singleton column' was applied 1 time.
  - rule 'objective: variable not used elsewhere' was applied 1 time.
  - rule 'presolve: iteration' was applied 1 time.
Problem closed by presolve.

CpSolverResponse summary:
status: INFEASIBLE
objective: NA
best_bound: NA
booleans: 0
conflicts: 0
branches: 0
propagations: 0
integer_propagations: 0
restarts: 0
lp_iterations: 0
walltime: 0.0109572
usertime: 0.010958
deterministic_time: 3.2426e-05
gap_integral: 0

infeasible for  8  robots
Status = INFEASIBLE
SufficientAssumptionsForInfeasibility = []
```

With this LOG, is there any way to figure out which constraint or variable is causing INFEASIBILITY? Any kind of help will be appreciated. thanks !

Comment: From that log it seems your 216 bool-vars together with implications + kBoolOr (should be possible to build one large implication-graph) are enough to render every problem infeasible. Here the solver seems to claim, that he inferred that from probing those bools. There are some unknowns in regards to: what did the solver reformulate into the implication-graph; why does he only need 108 probings for 208 vars (conflict-analysis?) and others but i think the core message is:    ignore your integer-vars, every integer-based constraint and the objective and only focus on bools: infeasible!

Comment: @sascha thanks, I will try debugging my boolean variables :)